# Having python script save captured video with date and time

Tags: python, datetime, video, video-capture

I'm trying to have my raspberry pi capture short videos and save them to a file with date and time. I have a short Python script that will capture video but it seems to overwrite the file with the latest video instead of saving each capture to a separate file.

```
import time
import picamera





with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.start_preview()
    camera.start_recording('/home/pi/Desktop/video.h264')
    time.sleep(60)
    camera.stop_recording()
    camera.stop_preview()
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it will.

Since you're always using the same path and file name to save the file it will override whatever was in the file `video.h264` before. You should implement an algorithm to avoid this.

You could name the files with the recording date in it.This will usually never be the same and you can rename your files later if you want so. The system date is available in the standard `time` module.
When you hit into problems with that we can help you.